# Is there a way to know which query to Hasura generated a given SQL output?

Tags: graphql, hasura

Assuming you've identified queries to inspect on a relational database that are likely running into the pitfall of sending too many too small queries and want to figure out where they come from to give the team sending them a heads up, is there any way to tell what graphql query generated it from the compiled SQL output?

Doing things the other way around where you inspect the compiled output of a known graphql query is easy. But there doesn't seem to be any easy way of acting on feedback from the actual DB?

Answer (score 1):

The Hasura Query log is probably a good place to start. Do you have [these logs](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/deployment/logging/) enabled for your Hasura installation?

If you look for logs of type `query-log` you'll get a structured JSON object with properties that will have the `operation` name as well as the GQL `query` that was submitted to Hasura and the `generated_sql` that was produced.

You'd be able to match on the `generated_sql` and then find the actual GQL that caused it using that approach